# Display the element without a scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm facing an unwanted horizontal scrollbar in an absolutely positioned div.
https://jsfiddle.net/br09ckuz/5

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.inner {
  height: 1000px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 10px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
  long content
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any workaround? I want to see the inner div horizontally without any scrollbar = the red border should be visible on both sides.

p.s. funny thing is that the issue is "fixed" in Chrome when you open and close the developer tools

**Edit**: found a solution - it seems to be enough to set `display: flex` on the parent element.

Comment: try min and max height proprties. ie, set min height for the parent div and max height  for child div

Comment: I can't see any horizontal scrollbar in the stack snippet and in the fiddle, only a vertical scrollbar, because you set `overflow: auto`. And the scrollbar stays there if dev tools are opened...

Comment: The scrollbar might not be there, but you can scroll the content and the box is clearly missing the right border = it's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the issue you're facing is caused by two things. The padding and border you're adding to `.inner`

When you add a border or padding to an element, they're not counted as part of its width by default.

To fix this, you need to things.

1. [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)
2. [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

You need `max-width: 100%` because you set an explicit width on `.inner`
You need `box-sizing: border-box` because you added padding, borders.

`max-width: 100%` ensures that `inner` never exceeds the width of `parent`
`box-sizing: border-box` ensures that its padding and borders are factored in when checking its width.

Lastly, you probably want to change its defined width to factor those in as well for visuals. So change the `.inner` width from 200px to 230px

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.inner {
  height: 1000px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 10px solid red;
  width: 230px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
    long content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
overflow: none;
```

To the parent element. It will solve your problem. You want to hide the scrollbar, right?

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't have a full horizontal content visible

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a vertical scrollbar is added, its horizontal width is included in the  width of the element (which is automatically calculated according to the contents, but not taking into account the vertical scrollbar), leaving less horizontal space for the contents. This can't be avoided.

The only thing you can do is to apply a `width` setting that also includes the borders and padding of the child element, PLUS the space for the vertical scrollbar, as in my snippet below (which works on Forefox, but might still cause a scrollbar in other browsers if their scrollbar is thicker that in Firefox)

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 245px;
}
.inner {
  height: 1000px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 10px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
  long content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as you said, this is not a cross browser solution. The only thing that worked for me is setting `display: inline-flex/flex` for parent element.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you cand add overflow: hidden;, but it will hide all your scrollbar, so you can specify overflow-y  to vertical scroll or overflow-x to your horizontal scroll.

[Here is a Sample code][1]
[1]: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_overflow-y